# How to show busy indicator for a WPF ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, model-binding, itemscontrol, busyindicator

I have an ItemsControl where I'm binding the ItemsSource property to my ViewModel.  It takes a few moments for the DataTemplate to render.  I would like to display a "busy indicator" while the DataTemplate renders.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Request.RequestDiscussions}">
```

Can this be done with DataTriggers or can it be done by the use of the ItemsControl's events?  Basically, I need an event when the binding begins and when the rendering has completed.

Comment: Maybe using a *virtualized* ItemsControl will remove the need for such a busy indicator.

Answer (score 1):

I wrap the item I want to have a busy indicator in a grid and add the indicator as a sibling that is centered horizontally and vertically.  This lets them overlap nicely.  Then I bind the visibility of the indicator to an IsBusy property on my viewmodel letting the bindings take care of everything.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The data in my ViewModel will have been loaded prior to binding to the ItemsControl.  When I set the binding of the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl, it's the rendering of the XAML that's taking a couple of moments to complete, not the actual task of retrieving the data.  I do like your idea of the grid wrapper and could see how that would work if I had an event to set the "IsBusy" when the binding starts and when the XAML has completed rendering.

Comment: You might be able to use the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` or `Control.OnApplyTemplate` events to know when rendering has started, but unfortunately I don't see a matching event for completion. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering(v=vs.110).aspx